# Characters being replaced by bbcode plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, bbcode

I have a bbcode plugin for wordpress.

But for some reason, if I post something like

`[i]v497212he2x2MfMi[/i]` the "X" character is outputted as `&#215;`, which is some other sort of X. How can I fix this?

Plugin code is below:

```
    class BBCode { 

    // Plugin initialization 
    function BBCode() { 
        // This version only supports WP 2.5+ (learn to upgrade please!) 
        if ( !function_exists('add_shortcode') ) return; 

        // Register the shortcodes 
        add_shortcode( 'b' , array(&$this, 'shortcode_bold') ); 
        add_shortcode( 'i' , array(&$this, 'shortcode_italics') ); 
    } 


    // No-name attribute fixing 
    function attributefix( $atts = array() ) { 
        if ( empty($atts[0]) ) return $atts; 

        if ( 0 !== preg_match( '#=("|\')(.*?)("|\')#', $atts[0], $match ) ) 
            $atts[0] = $match[2]; 

        return $atts; 
    } 


    // Bold shortcode 
    function shortcode_bold( $atts = array(), $content = NULL ) { 
        if ( NULL === $content ) return ''; 

        return '<strong>' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</strong>'; 
    } 


    // Italics shortcode 
    function shortcode_italics( $atts = array(), $content = NULL ) { 
        if ( NULL === $content ) return ''; 

        return '<em>' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</em>'; 
    } 

} 

// Start this plugin once all other plugins are fully loaded 
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $BBCode; $BBCode = new BBCode();' ) );
```

Comment: Could you provide some more faulty data it creates?

Comment: The BBCode class you provided works as expected.  Your problem is occurring elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transformation is taking place because of Wordpress's [wptexturize()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) function that returns given text with transformations of quotes to smart quotes, apostrophes, dashes, ellipses, the trademark symbol, and the multiplication symbol.

This is from WP 3.2.1 wp-includes/formatting.php line 55:

```
$dynamic_characters = array('/\'(\d\d(?:&#8217;|\')?s)/', '/\'(\d)/', '/(\s|\A|[([{<]|")\'/', '/(\d)"/', '/(\d)\'/', '/(\S)\'([^\'\s])/', '/(\s|\A|[([{<])"(?!\s)/', '/"(\s|\S|\Z)/', '/\'([\s.]|\Z)/', '/\b(\d+)x(\d+)\b/');
$dynamic_replacements = array('&#8217;$1','&#8217;$1', '$1&#8216;', '$1&#8243;', '$1&#8242;', '$1&#8217;$2', '$1' . $opening_quote . '$2', $closing_quote . '$1', '&#8217;$1', '$1&#215;$2');
```

The last regex in that `$dynamic_characters` array is the one turning the "X" into ×

As stated on the function page for wptexturize... `"[t]ext enclosed in the tags <pre>, <code>, <kbd>, <style>, <script>, <tt>, and [code] will be skipped."`, you can fix this by putting that bbcode in one of those tags, or use a plugin that can disable wptexturize, such as [InScript](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inscript/) or [Disabler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disabler/) or [Disable wptexturize](http://www.jasonlitka.com/2007/09/25/wordpress-plugin-disable-wptexturize/).